# Connect two routers so that the main router has control over the other

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I have already found an answer how to connect two routers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/365183/can-one-router-influence-other-who-is-linked-to-it). With the "same network" setup each device that tries to connect to the second router gets an IP address from the first. This is fine.

My question is, with this setup, is it still possible to block just the second routers IP (192.168.1.2 for example) and all the clients will be unable to connect? This is how I want it, but I am unsure if this is how it will work if I put them on the same network and disable DHCP on the second one.

Will I be able to block the second router and with that, all of its clients?

Comment: " all the clients will be unable to connect?" Connect to what? Other clients connected to the first router, or the internet?

Comment: i guess he means that he want to block the Wifi from hacking him desktop. i don't think he can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no for your basic router, since they are basically a device which connect everything together. but to a certain extend, you could turn on the firewall on you wired computer to filter out the wireless traffic.

you will need some more advanced model which support vlan and ACL.

Although you could try to setup LAN to LAN firewall, but i doubt if it would works, since typically they would consider they lie in same LAN segment. idea: connect at MAC level, you can saw their hardware address with arp command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the second router as a switch, you can use it as a, well, router. This is explained in the very question you linked in the section titled "How do I make my wired computers inaccessible from wireless?"

Basically, it shares the internet connection, but that's it. The two routers are two completely separate networks isolated from eachother.

Answer (score 0):

If the first router can block an IP, and you have your second router set up to always get the same IP, then yes, disabling access to 192.168.1.2 will prevent all clients connected to the second router from accessing the Internet (caveat being, the Internet is on the WAN port of router 1).  It will not stop traffic from being sent from Router 2 LAN to a host on Router 1's LAN, but traffic might not be able to get from a Router 1's LAN back to Router 2's LAN.